# Core-Plot Mac: show label when mouseover point in graph

Tags: macos, core-plot

I'm building a mac osx application with a nice graph in it made with Core-Plot. Its a line chart (scatterplot) with multiple points on it visualized with a plotsymbol circle.
My goal is to have a shown a label with the value of the point when a user mouse over a point in the chart.

I already have added NSTracking to the graph and this works but i'm lost in how to translate the plot point/plotsymbol to the coordinates so i know when it rollovers a point and show a label.

Somebody has an idea?
Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be something along those lines:

(I assume that the graph does not display any labels. Labels are being displayed only when the mouse is over a point on the graph.)

In the place where you handle the mouse logic, you would do:

```
    NSDecimalNumber *tickLocation = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:"The relevant axis value of the object you have the mouse over"];
    NSString *labelText = @"The text of the label";
    NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: labelText textStyle:axisSet."Whatever axis you want -X/Y".labelTextStyle];
    label.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
    label.offset = axisSet."Whatever axis you want -X/Y".labelOffset + axisSet."Whatever axis you want -X/Y".majorTickLength;
    label.rotation = M_PI/4;
    [customLabels addObject:label];
    axisSet."Whatever axis you want -X/Y".axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint:` method to find out which plot symbol is closest to a certain pixel. This method returns the datasource index of the point; you can look at the original data provided by your datasource to get the actual values. The `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` property controls how close the point has to be to the given point before it registers as a hit.